# How to store a risk-like game map

Tags: mysql, database-design

Imagine a multiplayer online game like [Risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_(game)) where there is a map represented by a NxN grid. Each cell can be free or occupied by a player. When a player access the page, the grid is displayed.

Assuming that:

- the grid is large (N > 40)
- the server hosts multiple games (i.e. multiple grids)

What could be the most efficient way to represent the grid in the database and to render it? My idea is to implement a `grid` table and a `cell` table containing the attributes `grid_id`, `occupying_user_id`, `pos_x`, `pos_y`, `other_properties`. However, I am not sure whether the rendering time would be acceptable with this strategy.

Comment: Render --  How?  Flash?  HTML5?  Other?  Grid -- even 40*40 lines would be trivial.

Comment: HTML5+JS. However, my main concern is the time needed for the query rather than  the frontend

Comment: What component is connecting to the database?

Comment: php+mysql but it is not a constraint

Comment: An "acceptable" rendering time is subjective.

Comment: "like Risk where there is a map represented by a NxN grid"--But that is not a useful description of a Risk map--it represents a math graph of places connected to other places. So you are not being clear about "a NxN grid". PS "Efficient" & "acceptible" mean nothing until you define them. Anyway what you should seek is "straightforward". Also this is both unclear & too broad. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 2):

Each **game** is independent of all other games, correct?  Then there is a `game_id` to segregate all the data from a game from other games.  Now, let's look at one "game"...

There are thousand(s) of cells in your grid, but perhaps only hundred(s) of cells have interesting information in them (such as cities, armies, players, etc)?  And each interesting cells are connected by a few lines to other cells, with a total of hundred(s) of lines?

I recommend (if using PHP) building a small number of **classes**:

- The world:  Mostly having the 2D array of cells, plus a few methods for global actions.  Perhaps the array of links between cells goes here.
- The interesting cells:  name, attributes, array of who is on the cell, etc.  Plus methods for maniuplating the contents.
- Player:  his tokens, his booty, whatever.
- Token:  x & y coorinates at the moment, etc.

Moving a token would reach into various objects --

- To see which cells it can move to
- To see who it needs to interact with
- Changing the x&y coordinates, etc.

As for "size".  What I have described is "small".  A single server could easily hand hundred(s), maybe thousands of "games" running simultaneously.  Let's do some math:

- In 1 game, 1 player makes 1 move each minute
- a move involves 20 SQL statements

If there are 100 games running, that is 33 queries per second.  Not a problem.  A thousand games might be a problem.

**Rendering** means drawing on the screen, doesn't it?  PHP has no *direct* rendering commands.  You still need something to interact with each player's screen.

The more you put into JavaScript and the less AJAX you use, the more you offloading the rendering to each user.  I assume each player has his own computer (or smartphone or ...)  The analysis above assumes that most of the work is in PHP.  But if you push most of the work into the clients, then you can handle even more "games".

At the extreme, the entire game is played in each player's device, and the central computer is only used for relaying messages such as "I moved my piece to Timbuktu" which would be encoded more like "In game 17, player 3 moved token 4 to [31,42] and did action 5."  At that point, the other players' client code must replicate that action and its effects.

Note in this last example I imply that a single program can handle multiple games.  With PHP (with HTML and AJAX), that is essentially the way things work.  That is, you have a single set of code, and every time it must be told which game it is looking at.

**Who renders**?  Keep in mind that either the server (with PHP, etc) or the client (with JS, etc) can orchestrate the rendering (draw line from x1,y1 to x2,y2; show image; etc), but ultimately the client does the grunt work of producing pixels on a screen.

A well-designed system splits the effort between client and server at the optimal point, depending on that is being done.  For example, if you want to show a token being picked up from one xy location and placed in another, you need to decide whether you will have it vanish from one spot and show up at the other, or whether you will show it being dragged from one spot to the other.  The server should think of it the first way; the client should be burdened with the details of drag and drop (if you go that direction).

Answer (score 1):

If they are fixed territories(like how risk has big blocks that aren't necessarily grid format), then you could just use Territories table with unique identifier for each piece of land.  Something like TerritoryID, TerritoryName, IsOccupied(bit),OccupiedByID(FK to PlayerID), DateTime, etc.  For the graphics part, you would be able to just create a block and design it however on the front end as long as you have something to point it to on in the database ( ie I can draw China however I want in program as long as I can point to China object in db)

Then maybe a players table with PlayerID(PK), PlayerName, Datetime, and do something like that approach.  You'd also need other tables for player account information probably.

If you are trying to represent each individual spaces with lattitude/longitude, I'd do it very similar to what you were describing with pos_x, pos_y as long as you have unique identifier for each and include IsOccupied bit along with time.

Comment: Thank you. As for the rendering, I was more concerned about the time needed to query the DB and generate the frontend elements accordingly, rather than their appearance

Comment: Makes sense.  Well the speed would depend on a ton of factors like hardware, network, traffic/load etc but you could easily make this design fast if it's got adequate hardware along with proper indexes and set-based queries.

Comment: You don't really need isOccupied and OccupiedBy.  If OccupiedBy is >0 or perhaps OccupiedBy Is Not Null then the space is occupied.

Comment: Good point, Is not null would work for everything OccupiedBy would.